# Typeahead/TypeScript - multiple Datasets of different generic type

Tags: generics, typescript, typeahead.js

I have two Datasets, each of a different generic type. Everything works well except the for the initialisation where for

```
var localDataset: Twitter.Typeahead.Dataset<Node>;
var globalDataset: Twitter.Typeahead.Dataset<Budget>;
...
typeahead(options, localDataset, globalDataset);
```

I get the error

> Error:(130, 13) TS2453: The type argument for type parameter 'T'
>   cannot be inferred from the usage. Consider specifying the type
>   arguments explicitly.  Type argument candidate 'Node' is not a valid
>   type argument because it is not a supertype of candidate 'Budget'.

As a workaround I cast Datasets as , but what would be the correct solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As a workaround I cast Datasets as , but what would be the correct solution

Anything that consolidates the two type e.g. a `map` or just:

```
type NodeOrBudget = Node | Budget;

var localDataset: Twitter.Typeahead.Dataset<NodeOrBudget>;
var globalDataset: Twitter.Typeahead.Dataset<NodeOrBudget>;
...
typeahead(options, localDataset, globalDataset);
```